# Fail to inherit BYPASSRLS

Tags: postgresql, permissions

In my Postgres database, I create a role `group` with BYPASSRLS. I assign `group` to user `archibald`. I expect `user` to have BYPASSRLS. However, I find the user cannot bypass the row-level security.

I can work around it by granting BYPASSRLS to archibald directly, but I would like to manage this by group.

Code:

```
create role group nologin bypassrls;
grant usage on schema public to group;
grant select on all tables in schema public to group;

create user archibald password 'password';
grant group to archibald;
```

Expected result: `archibald` should be able to see all rows in all tables.
Actual result: He sees nothing due to row-level security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like all other properties of a role, you cannot inherit `BYPASSRLS`. Only privileges and ownership on objects and membership in roles are inherited.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, [`BYPASSRLS` is a *role attribute*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/role-attributes.html) and those are not inheritable. That being said, a `GRANT` establishing group membership by default comes [`with SET option`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html#SQL-GRANT-DESCRIPTION-ROLES) which allows the direct member to impersonate/switch to the group role and make use of the group role's attributes:

```
create table test(a int);
insert into test values (1),(2);
alter table test enable row level security;
create policy test_policy on test as permissive for all using(a=1);

create role group_ nologin bypassrls;
grant usage on schema public to group_;
grant select on all tables in schema public to group_;

create user archibald password 'password';
grant group_ to archibald with set option /*that's default, it's here for clarity*/;
```

As user `postgres`, you can see a=2 listed because of `bypassrls`. Otherwise the policy would hide it.

```
set role postgres;
select * from test;
```

| a |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

User `archibald` won't see `a=2` because `bypassrls` wasn't inherited from `group_` they belong to:

```
set role archibald;
select * from test;
```

| a |
| --- |
| 1 |

`archibald` can impersonate the `group_` role and use their `bypassrls` to see `a=2`

```
set role group_;
select * from test;
```

| a |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Qd_ldpAM)